# How to clear combo?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I try to clear value of a particular combo. Sometimes it happens, sometimes - not. I tried different methods, but to no avail. Now, I do it like this:

```
mycombo.reset();
mycombo.clearValue();
mycombo.applyEmptyText();
```

And yes, my combo has `forceSelection:true`.

I even checked these three 'magic' lines of code:

```
mycombo.clearValue();
mycombo.applyEmptyText();
mycombo.getPicker().getSelectionModel().doMultiSelect([], false);
```

But I still have the same picture. Resetting of the combo happens by chance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In combo there is magic method called `assertValue` which often causes some issues:

```
assertValue: function() {
    var me = this,
        value = me.getRawValue(),
        rec, currentValue;

    if (me.forceSelection) {
        if (me.multiSelect) {
            // For multiselect, check that the current displayed value matches the current
            // selection, if it does not then revert to the most recent selection.
            if (value !== me.getDisplayValue()) {
                me.setValue(me.lastSelection);
            }
        } else {
            // For single-select, match the displayed value to a record and select it,
            // if it does not match a record then revert to the most recent selection.
            rec = me.findRecordByDisplay(value);
            if (rec) {
                currentValue = me.value;
                // Prevent an issue where we have duplicate display values with
                // different underlying values.
                if (!me.findRecordByValue(currentValue)) {
                    me.select(rec, true);
                }
            } else {
                me.setValue(me.lastSelection);
            }
        }
    }
    me.collapse();
}
```

Basically when you don't use `multiSelect` then `lastSelection` is used always, when you try to set value which cannot be found at store.
I usually add dummy record to store, which corresponds to empty value. The problem will come back if you need to set `allowBlank` to false.

As an alternative to add dummy record you can override `assertValue` method like this:

```
assertValue: function () {
    var me = this,
        value = me.getRawValue();

    if (me.forceSelection && me.allowBlank && Ext.isEmpty(value)) {
        me.setValue(value);
        me.collapse();
        return;
    }

    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```